# Definition of the multiplication matrix of element of finite field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, cryptography

I've been reading this article [XOR-counts and lightweight multiplication with fixed elements in binary finite fields](https://rdcu.be/bRjca) and I came across the term **Multiplication matrix** and I've wondered if that's some terminology from finite fields theory I perhaps don't know (English is not my native language and I don't study math in English). It seems really odd that the author mentions the term in an abstract and doesn't define it properly (but then maybe it's just a widely used term).
From what I've understood multiplication matrix is matrix such that: $\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{2^n} \exists A \in \mathbb{F}_2$ such that $\forall x \in \mathbb{F}_{2^n}: \alpha \cdot x = A \cdot \hat{x}$, where $\hat{x}$ is element $x$ written as an n-dimensional vector over $\mathbb{F}_2$. 
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplication by an element of $\mathbb F_{2^n}$ on elements of $\mathbb F_{2^n}$ produces a $\mathbb F_2$ linear transformation on $\mathbb F_{2^n}$. As such, you can pick a basis of $\mathbb F_{2^n}$ (necessarily having $n$ elements) and find a transformation matrix (an element of $M_n(\mathbb F_2)$) for each element.

Then the explanation in the paper is quite clear (p 286, the second page of the pdf):

> Our goal in this work is to explore some connections and properties of the direct and sequential XOR-count metrics and then to apply these to get some theoretical results regarding optimal implementations of matrices that represent multiplication with a ﬁxed ﬁeld element $α ∈ \mathbb F_{2^k}$. Optimal choices of these matrices (called **multiplication matrices**) can then be used for local optimizations of matrices over $\mathbb F_{2^k}$.

As mentioned in the paper in several places, they are optimizing to minimize the number of XOR operations required to perform multiplication.

Comment: Could you please describe a way to finding such a transformation matrix? I realize that when I pick a basis $B$, the element $\alpha x$ has only one way of being written in this basis. I just can't think of a way to get matrix $A$ from $x$ and $\alpha x$. I can even think of a general example where multiple matrices that fulfill these criteria exist. Does $B^{-1}AB$ change with basis? By my geometrical intuition, it shouldn't, since linear transformation just a rotation of vector space. But I guess that might be the goal of this article: to find in which basis has $[A]_B$ the lowest XOR-count.

Comment: @kytka it is too complicated to write in a comment, and it sounds anyway like you need to struggle through the details yourself.  It is a simple thing, except if you have not really understood how a matrix represents a transformation in terms of a particular basis.  I would advise you to construct the field of four elements, then choose a basis over the field of two elements, then pick an element that is not 0 or 1, and work out what its matrix is.